# how to broadcast packets in NS2? i want to create program (tcl/c++) in which each node broadcasts packet

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am doing my  project in wireless network using ns2. I want to create program where each node in the network broadcasts packet. Please help

Comment: What have you tried already? Any errors we can assess? Can you provide some code to review?

Comment: I tried this code on given link : http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/archive/ns-users/webarch/2001/msg05889.html   I used Redhat 6 in Vmware 10. But after running c code it was giving errors that library files mentioned in the code was not found

Answer (score 0):

May be some hints here (fastbroadcast)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/fastbroadcast/

-